# How can you use the sorted() function to print a list in reverse alphabetical order? (Python)

Tags: python, function, reverse

I'm a true newbie in Python. Using a learning book I've got this exercise among others.
I do know how to do that with  method, but not with  a function sorted([, , , ] ).
I've tried different approaches to try to understand but i didn't.

So in the most simple words. How do you do it?

Thanks you

Comment: `sorted('abcdef',reverse=True)`

Comment: What do you mean, "I do know how to do that to a method, but not to a function"?

Comment: Ask python. `help(sorted)` gives you `sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list` which is somewhat cryptic but gives you the name of an interesting parameter and the fact that it returns a new list. That's all you need on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
sorted('abcdef',reverse=True)
```

Comment: And how can I print it?

Comment: `print sorted('abcdef',reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If I want to sort the whole list

```
wow=['usa', 'australia', 'brazil', 'ireland']
print(sorted(wow))
print(sorted(wow, reverse=True))
```

Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I come across a similar exercise in the book **Python Crash Course A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming**.

If you want to reverse the letters in a string, you could try this, just put the string inside the parentheses.

`print(sorted("happyday",reverse=True))`.

outcome: `['y', 'y', 'p', 'p', 'h', 'd', 'a', 'a']`

If you want to reverse the elements in a list, you could try this:

```
    want_to_visit=["Berlin","Thailand","London","Greek","Agentina"]
    print(sorted(want_to_visit,reverse=True))
```

outcome: `['Thailand', 'London', 'Greek', 'Berlin', 'Agentina']`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cities = ["London", "Paris", "Rome", "Los Angeles", "New York"]    
cities.sort(reverse=True)    
print(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hilarious! I was just doing the same exercise and having the same problem. It is from the "PYTHON CRASH COURSE" chapter 3.8 to be exact.

cities = ["London", "Paris", "Rome", "Los Angeles", "New York"]
cities.sort(reverse=True)
print(cities)

works to permanently sort the list into reverse alphabetical order whereas

print (sorted(cities,reverse=True))

gives you a temporary reverse alphabetical sort of the list